# How to get other citations than \cite work with chicago package. E.g. \fullcite

Tags: citing, chicago-style

I have gotten a template from my university in which I have added a bibliography. Since I am not very experienced with LaTex, I have no clue about all the packages that are included in my template.

The problem I have is that I can only use the `\cite` command. But since I want to use more precise citations this is not enough. So i found out about the `\fullcite` or even better the `\footfullcite`  commands which are supposed to be included in the chicago package. Unfortunately, if I try to use `\fullcite`, I get the error message:

```
"! Undefined control sequence.
l.96 \fullcite
{han2005macht}"
```

The `literaturvz.bib` file includes the following code:

```
@book{han2005macht,
    Address = {Stuttgart},
    Author = {Han, Byung-Chul},
    Date-Added = {2015-11-23 15:08:53 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2015-11-23 15:13:57 +0000},
    Hdsurl = {https://hds.hebis.de/ubffm/Record/HEB130215988},
    Isbn = {978-3-15-018356-4},
    Publisher = {Reclam},
    Series = {Reclams Universal-Bibliothek},
    Title = {Was ist Macht?},
    Uniqueid = {HEB130215988},
    Volume = 18356,
    Year = 2005,
    Bdsk-Url-1 = {http://scans.hebis.de/HEBCGI/show.pl?13021598_toc.pdf}}
```

And here is an example of my file which is giving me the errors:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,titlepage,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{german}
\usepackage[a4paper, top=2.5cm, footskip=0pt, headheight=0.8cm, headsep=1.1cm, lmargin=3cm, rmargin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{chicago}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{extramarks}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage[right]{eurosym}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}[]
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2}
\fancyhead[L]{\slshape \small \firstleftmark}
\fancyhead[R]{\normalsize\thepage} \fancyfoot{}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{grafiken/KITLogo_RGB.pdf}
\vspace*{2cm}
\begin{center}
    \Huge{Title
    \\}
    \vspace*{1cm}
    \huge{Author\\}
    \small{(Matrikelnummer: 00000000)}
    \vspace*{1cm}\\
    \Large{
        Bachelorarbeit
    \\}
    \vspace*{2cm}
    \normalsize{
        Fakultät für Wirtschaftswissenschaften\\
        Institut für Wirtschaftstheorie und Statistik\\
        Lehrstuhl für Wirtschaftstheorie
    }
\end{center}
\vspace{2cm}
\begin{center}
\large{Wintersemester 2015}
\end{center}
\vspace*{3cm}
\small{
\begin{tabular}[ht]{l c l}
  Gutachter:                                    & \hfill  & Prof. Dr. Susanne     Fuchs-Seliger\\
\end{tabular}
}

\begin{textblock}{10}[0,0](4,16.8)
\tiny{ 
    KIT -- Universität des Landes Baden-Württemberg und nationales     Forschungszentrum der Helmholtz-Gesellschaft
}
\end{textblock}

\begin{textblock}{10}[0,0](14,16.75)
\large{
    \textbf{www.kit.edu} 
}
\end{textblock}

\end{titlepage}

\thispagestyle{empty}\clearpage

%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------    ------------------------------------------------------
\rmfamily \pagestyle{fancy} \setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\newtheorem{satz}{Satz}
\newtheorem{lemma}[satz]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{folgerung}[satz]{Folgerung}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[satz]{Definition}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\renewcommand{\proofname}{Beweis}
\newcommand\macht{\textit{Ma\-cht }}

\pagenumbering{roman}\setcounter{page}{3} \tableofcontents
\newcounter{roemisch} \setcounter{roemisch}{\value{page}}
\clearpage

\setcounter{page}{2} \pagenumbering{arabic}
\section{Einleitung}

Abc\footcite{han2005macht}

\newpage
%Literaturverzeichnis----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Literaturverzeichnis}
\bibliographystyle{abbrvdin}
\bibliography{literaturvz}

\end{document}
```

I've been searching for hours now and tried to implement the natbib or biblatex packages which didn't work either. So I really hope one of you can help me since I am totally over-challenged here.

Comment: There is a package `footbib` for putting full bibliography citations in a footnote. Maybe that would help.

Comment: Welcome! Biblatex provides both `\fullcite` and `\footfullcite` and there is a `chicago` style for Biblatex (not one of the standard ones, but a contributed one). I don't know anything about the package **chicago** so I couldn't tell you whether it should provide these or not. For the chicago Biblatex style, you really want to use Biber so you compile pdflatex -> biber -> pdflatex (rather than using bibtex).

Comment: @Dan : tried including footbib already. It gives me the following error:

! Package footbib Error: the output routine of LaTeX changed.

Comment: @cfr : the chicago package is the package formerly known as biblatex-chicago-notes-df. It's documentation says that it includes \fullcite \footfullcite etc. which is why I am so confused.

If I try to add the biblatex-chicago style which you mentioned, I get the following error.
! LaTeX Error: Command \bibhang already defined.

I am pretty sure there must be a coding mistake oder a package overflow in my template, but I don't know enough about LaTex to find it.

Comment: On my system, **chicago** is a BibTeX style for use with the relevant `.bst` files. **biblatex-chicago** is the Biblatex style. You are loading a BibTeX package but trying to use commands from Biblatex. `chicago.sty` is dated from 1992, long before Biblatex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the Biblatex style, you need to remove

```
\usepackage{chicago}
```

and

```
\bibliographystyle{abbrvdin}
\bibliography{literaturvz}
```

Then, in the preamlbe add

```
\usepackage{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{literaturvz.bib}
```

and in your document, add

```
\printbibliography
```

So, minimising your example somewhat, we get something like this:

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{han2005macht, Address = {Stuttgart}, Author = {Han, Byung-Chul}, Date-Added = {2015-11-23 15:08:53 +0000}, Date-Modified = {2015-11-23 15:13:57 +0000}, Hdsurl = {https://hds.hebis.de/ubffm/Record/HEB130215988}, Isbn = {978-3-15-018356-4}, Publisher = {Reclam}, Series = {Reclams Universal-Bibliothek}, Title = {Was ist Macht?}, Uniqueid = {HEB130215988}, Volume = 18356, Year = 2005, Bdsk-Url-1 = {http://scans.hebis.de/HEBCGI/show.pl?13021598_toc.pdf}}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,titlepage,12pt,ngerman]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm, footskip=0pt, headheight=0.8cm, headsep=1.1cm, lmargin=3cm, rmargin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{\jobname}

\begin{document}
Abc\footcite{han2005macht}

\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Literaturverzeichnis}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Compiling with `pdflatex` -> `biber` -> `pdflatex` produces the following result:

[image: footnote citation and bibliography]

By the way, in

```
\usepackage{tikz}[]
```

what is the `[]` supposed to do?

Also, commands such as `\huge` do not take arguments. They are switches. So

```
\huge{abc\\}def
```

is equivalent to

```
\huge abc\\def
```

Other things being equal, everything until the end of the current group will be `\huge`. To limit the effect, put the switch in a group:

```
{\huge abc\\}def
```

Normally, `\\` should not be used to break a line, of course. But, in your case, it is being used within a `center` environment so it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Wow, first of all thank you so much for giving me such a comprehensive answer.
Unfortunately I am still having problems.
I changed the code as you said but when I'm trying to compile with biber I am getting the following error:
INFO - This is Biber 2.2
INFO - Logfile is 'ba_m_t.tex.blg'
ERROR - Cannot find control file 'ba_m_t.tex.bcf'! - did you pass the "backend=biber" option to BibLaTeX?
INFO - ERRORS: 1

Could it be because of my bibliography not being in the main file but being a separate file?

Comment: About the tikz-package: This was being written like that in the template.
Same goes for the \huge commands. The template came with the front-page being set. Should I change it?

Comment: @Maurice There should be no problem with the bibliography in a separate file. This is, in fact, the normal situation. The problem is that you are running `biber <filename>.tex` and you need to omit the `.tex`. It needs to look for `ba_m_t.bcf` and if you say `biber ba_m_t` or `biber ba_m_t.bcf`, it will. If you say `biber ba_m_t.tex` it will look for `ba_m_t.tex.bcf` instead. About the template, all I can tell you is: it is wrong. Templates are generally of poor quality. If the code gives the output your institution wants, leave it. But don't do it that way in other documents!

Comment: You, Sir, are amazing!!! Everything is working now. Thank you so much! I got two last aesthetic questions, though. Is there a way to have biblatex-chicago use a german bibliography-style? Maybe looking similar to the abbrvdin-style. That would be terrific. And also, I really like the way it cites, but printing the ISBN in every citation is a bit of an overkill. I've found \shortcite and other cites, but I can't find a full cite just without the ISBN. (I still want the ISBN to appear in the reference list, though). Do you know any fix here?

Comment: @Maurice I recommend you ask new questions about those issues as I think you'll get better solutions that way. I used to use `biblatex-chicago` but not the notes style, and I haven't used it for a while so I'm really not familiar with the options it offers for customisation.

Comment: Alright, will do. Once again, thank you very much!